# Using multiple windows with Storyboards (Mac OS X development)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I have two window controllers (with their own view controllers) on a storyboard.

In one window, I have the main program, a basic text editor with an NSTextView. In the other window, I have a single button.

I found out how to get the window to display by linking it to a menu item. It works.

The main window is linked to my ViewController class by default. The second window is also linked to the ViewController class and has its button linked to an IBAction in the ViewController class.

I have some simple code in the IBAction that basically tells the NSTextView to change its font size to a much bigger font. I have confirmed that the code itself works when called in other methods.

The button works, **BUT** it is using an entirely different instance of my ViewController class. So in result: the text size doesn't change.

So my main question here is **how do I get an IBAction in one window to affect an object in another window**.

I hope I did an *alright* job at explaining myself. Keep in mind this is my first Stack Overflow question:) I tried my best to research this question but mostly found information on iOS development and using XIB files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have two windows with the same controller class but want what happens in one window to affect the other window. The easiest way is going to be with notifications. When the button is clicked in one window a notification gets posted that all instances of `ViewController` receive and respond to by changing the font size as needed. You could also look into setting a user default when the button is clicked and using bindings to keep the text field's font size tied to the current default.

Comment: Notifications seem to do the trick. Thanks! Is there a way to send an object through the NSNotification. For example, lets say I had a colorwell instead of a button. Is there a way to send the NSColor value of the color well through an NSNotification?

Comment: You can pass a dictionary in the userInfo parameter that can contain most anything you want. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotification_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNotification/initWithName:object:userInfo:

Comment: Thanks! Great suggestions, but today I found something that will work even better for me: Shared instances:)